Is there a difference between 'sit at home' and 'stay at home'?
Is it possible to say:

I can go to the theatre instead of sitting at home.

If it is, is there a difference between sit at home and stay at home?

What is it about the sentence that makes you doubt it is 'possible to say'?

The choice of 'sitting' merely implies that you would be relaxing rather than keeping busy during that evening at home.

In your sentence we would often say "instead of just sitting at home" -- this emphasizes that staying home is less active or preferable.

@Barmar - If you don't 'know this intuitively', you could also be learning British English!

This is not a proofreading question, and closing it for that reason is an error. Also  there are legitimate uses for “stay at home”, so Barmar’s comment is a rude put-down.

The body of the question indeed makes it appear that it is a mere proofreading question, but the title probably makes it clearer what the OP is really asking. There is a subtle difference between using stay and sit in this context, which goes beyond what can be easily figured out by consulting general-purpose dictionaries, and so may be worth explicating here. The question should, therefore, be reopened.

All: If you think the question should be reopened, edit it first so that it's clear that it's not a proofreading question. Currently it is, and it's liable to be closed if it is reopened.

Alex, can you edit the question so that what is now in its title (is there a difference between sit at home and stay at home?) is incorporated into the body of the question?
